# Android - Putting Multiple ASyncTaskLoader classes as InnerClasses in a "manager" Class

Tags: java, android, subclass, inner-classes, asynctaskloader

Good Afternoon, I am developing an Android application that has ArrayLists of CustomObjects.

These objects are generated at run-time and their properties are set from SQLite data. Since I am using SQlite i will be requiring the use of some sort of AsyncTask, and I believe the AsyncTaskLoader fits the bill.

I want to create some sort of "Manager" class that will manage the creation/loading/updating of these custom objects (There are 3 custom object types). What i want to do is create the "Manager" class and have 3 inner classes that will extend AsyncTaskLoader (As well as other various functions as required).

My question to you is, How can my MainActivity work with these inner classes that are a part of the "Manager" class? How will MainActivity receive the callbacks? Is there a better solution than this?

Something like this...

```
public class ObjectManager implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Object>>{

    private Context mContext;
    private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
    private ObjectManagerCallBacks mObjectManagerCallBacks;

    public ObjectManager(Context context, LoaderManager loaderManager){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mObjectManagerCallBacks = (ObjectManagerCallBacks) context;
        this.mLoaderManager = loaderManager;

        mLoaderManager.initLoader(*id#1*,null,this);
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(*id#2*,null,this);
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(*id#3*,null,this);
    }

    public interface ObjectManagerCallBacks{
        void contentUpdated(int loader,ArrayList<Object> newData);
    }

@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<Object>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id){
        case #1:
            return new #1Loader(mContext);
        case #2:
            return new #2Loader(mContext);
        case #3:
            return new #3Loader(mContext);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Object>> loader, ArrayList<Object> data) {
    switch (loader.getId()){
        case #1:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#1LOADER,data);
            break;
        case #2:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#2LOADER,data);
            break;
        case #3:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#3LOADER,data);
            break;
        default:
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Object>> loader) {
    switch (loader.getId()){
        case WORKOUT_LOADER:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#1LOADER,null);
            break;
        case EXERCISE_LOADER:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#2LOADER,null);
            break;
        case USER_EXERCISE_LOADER:
            mObjectManagerCallbacks.contentUpdated(#3LOADER,null);
            break;
        default:
    }
}

    //Various methods for object maintenance will go here
    //And here
    //And here...

    private class LoaderTask1 extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArayList<CustomObject1>>{
    }

    private class LoaderTask2 extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArayList<CustomObject2>>{
    }

    private class LoaderTask3 extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArayList<CustomObject3>>{
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your time.

My Solution that worked --

I ended up creating 3 inner classes in my CustomObjectManager class. These 3 classes extend AsyncTaskLoader. I followed a few guides on the task loader and managed to get them to load my cursor as well as create my objects asynchronously. I also created an interface to communicate these innerclasses with my MainActivity to notify ListViews that there is new data to be displayed.

Comment: ...has an ArrayList of ... ... ... ?

Comment: just use a CursorLoader

Comment: Yup. Cursor loader is the way to go.

Comment: So just use a CursorLoader then build the objects inside that?

Comment: @hitch.united what objects? your data source is sqlite db, so return Cursors and use [Simple]CursorAdapter

Comment: @pskink, The only reason im using SQL is to store the custom object properties so I can rebuild them when the application starts back up. I ended up going with AsyncTaskLoader to query in the background then create an array of custom objects out of it. Will update my post shortly for others.

Comment: @hitch.united why custom interface? why not to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html ?

Comment: @pskink I am actually using that for my manager class with the 3 Asynctaskloaders, once onLoadFinished is called by them they use the custom interface to let my MainActivity know that the content needs to be refreshed. AFAIK this seems to be a good route, it is working pretty well so far. Let me update my pseudo code in my question to reflect where I am at with this. Thanks for all of your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create some sort of "Manager" class that will manage the creation/loading/updating of these custom objects...

This is exactly the purpose of the `LoaderManager`... to manage one or more loaders across a single activity/fragment instance. In my opinion, creating a separate `ObjectManager` class whose only purpose is to serve as a wrapper around the loaders is only going to complicate your activity/fragment logic. Just have your `Activity` implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface and you'll achieve the exact same thing without the extra code.